# JSON Async/Await Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, async-await, syntax-error

When I hardcode a value it works perfectly

```
username = "leomessi";
let id = await (await fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`)).json();
console.log(id.graphql.user.id);
```

But when I make it a function

```
const userToID = (username) => {
    let id = await (await fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`)).json();
    return id.graphql.user.id;
}
```

it says **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

Comment: You're trying to use `await` inside a function that is not `async`.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, you are using `await`. This means you should expect to define your wrapping function as `async`.

```js
const userToID = async (username) => {
    let id = await (await fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`)).json();
    return id.graphql.user.id;
}
```

Comment: Is there anything after the first?

Comment: I only had one single `console.log()` method, awaiting for the return value of a single callback embedded within it. Wrapping the entire statement with an async IIFE, was more succinct, rather than defining a wrapper async function, then calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `async` keyword for functions where you want to `await`

```js
const userToID = async (username) => {
    let id = await (await fetch(`https://www.instagram.com/${username}/?__a=1`)).json();
    return id.graphql.user.id;
}
```

Comment: But now the function doesn't return an integer but a promise

Comment: `async` functions are expected to return a promise because you are able to resolve promises inside them. You'll have to account for this in the rest of your code; if you give me more code context I can help you work it in correctly

Comment: @EmilianoJerochim you're handling the result of `fetch` and that's asynchronous. You cannot convert async code to run synchronously.